# ambiguous class with namespace names in 2 dlls

Tags: c#, instance, ddl

I've imported 2 dlls to my application (third party)
Now both of them have a namespace with same name.
For example A.B
and in both of them there is a class again with a same name.
Now I want to create an instance of one of them, but because the namespace and class names are same, the compiler goes ambiguous.
How can I specify witch dll used in the place?

Comment: if below answers doesnt work then you're screwed :)

Comment: Luckily one of them works :-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have 2 assemblies (`ClassLibrary1.dll` and `ClassLibrary2.dll`) that both define the same class in the same namespace:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
    }
}
```

Now in the consuming project you could define an additional alias in the references of the class library:

[image]

And now you could do the following to help the compiler disambiguate:

```
extern alias lib1;
extern alias lib2;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var barFromLib1 = new lib1::Foo.Bar();
        var barFromLib2 = new lib2::Foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was similar to a problem I was having but in my case, it was my own code (a small helper class) that I needed to use in 2 different DLLs that were in turn being used by an EXE. Darin's solution worked great! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just a little improvment or enhanced information: If you have multiple usings, the "extern alias lib1;"-line must be the very first of those usings (But also MS VS informs you about that).

Comment: your answer doesn't provide answer to question.Please read the question carefully

Comment: Unfortunately I can not comment, otherwise I would have prefered that to share my knowledge. But as you might read, my answer is just an "improvement", not quite an answer.