# Error in Visual Studio 2013 when including JetBrains ReSharper via NuGet

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, resharper, nuget

When I include JetBrains-ReSharper  my project using NuGet Package Manager, and then I try to rebuild the project, it shows an error.

> Error 14 The type 'System.Threading.LazyInitializer' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll' and 'Project\packages\JetBrains.ReSharper.SDK.8.2.1158\bin\System.Threading.dll' Project\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

Can anybody can help me to solve the problem ?

Comment: You have ambiguity between the classes defined in two different dlls which are being referenced. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203813/ambiguous-class-with-namespace-names-in-2-dlls)

Comment: Are you trying to add ReSharper SDK libraries to MVC project?!

Comment: Yes, I was trying to add ReSharper SDK libraries to MVC project.

Comment: It has no meaning. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conflict in Threading.task.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950599/conflict-in-threading-task-dll)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, because ReSharper is a .net 3.5 application, and due to the way the SDK is set up, it includes references to the .net 3.5 compatible System.Threading.Tasks.dll back port Microsoft initially released with RX. The unfortunate part is that this file is referenced even if your plugin is a .net 4 project, and so you get conflicts with the real System.Threading.Tasks.

You can change your project to be .net 3.5, but then (again, due to the way the SDK is set up) you'll get other warnings about .net 4 assemblies that are referenced, but shouldn't be. Essentially, you just have to ignore those warnings. We're working on fixing all of this for 9.0.

However, as @derigel mentions in the comments - adding the ReSharper SDK to an MVC project is a little weird, and frankly, won't work. The ReSharper SDK is for building ReSharper plugin extensions. If you want to install ReSharper, download it from here: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/